# C++ Why Does this Write in Japanese?

Tags: c++

I have my code which writes data into a text file. My problem is for some odd reason, it writes in Japanese! Obviously I cannot read Japanese, but how can I write it into a regular text format. Pretend the data[i].name and password have a char [10] value. And they already write in the file, the problem is the language it writes in.

```
// variables
FILE *streaming; 
const int amount = 5;
profile data[5];

if (!(streaming = fopen("Profiles.txt",  "r" )))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            data[i].name[0] = 0;
            data[i].password[0] = 0;
        }
        streaming = fopen( "Profiles.txt", "wb" );
        fwrite (data, sizeof(data), 1 , streaming); 
        fclose (streaming);
    }
```

Comment: Please back this with a screenshot ... And show us what profile is made of

Comment: I'd bet on it simply being random bytes at the end of `password` and `name` since you write all of their data, setting their first byte to `\0` doesn't help here. It'd probably go away if you completely zero it out.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/upqayryr3/

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour, since you are reading from uninitialized objects.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl, How can I fix this?

Comment: @KerrekSB,  so what should I do to fix this?

Comment: @Bryan: Understand what `fwrite` does and use it with deliberation and purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data[i].name[0] = 0;` sets the first element of what I presume to be a character array to 0. It does absolutely nothing with the rest of the character array. Whatever random crap was in the rest of the character array is still there.

`fwrite (data, sizeof(data), 1 , streaming);` will mindlessly write the everything inside the array of profile structures, including all of the random crap after the first element of the `name` and `password` arrays inside each profile.

To completely clear the profiles, assuming there is nothing in profile that will respond badly to memset, try

`memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));`

Don't bother asking your doctor. Post your profile structure and we'll know for sure if memset is right for you.

Comment: Your first part solved it for me, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: One quick question, how can I put a '#' after the data[i].password.

Comment: @Bryan Immediately after the last valid character or after the entire field?

Comment: At the end, should I just use another data[i].seperator? or is their an easier way?

Comment: @Bryan What you have is much easier until formatting the data, like inserting a character after a field of uncertain length, comes into play, and then it loses usefulness really quickly. The better way can't be explained in a 500 character comment block. Read up on using fstream, do it right and you can have stuff that works just like cin and cout do when reading from the console.